# SurfaceView only update UI once

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I was trying to learn how to use SurfaceView, since I need to use it in a future project. I read that if I need to update the UI quickly, it is preferable to use SurfaceView with the help of a thread.

The purpose of my code is to be able to print on a bitmap, the pattern of a 'B',here is the code:

```
public void testTransition(Canvas canvas) {
    if (canvas != null) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        Log.i("Thread", "Running...");
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            if (test[y] == 1) {

                canvas.drawBitmap(ledBitMap, (x - diameterLeds) / 2, diameterLeds * y, paint);

            }

        }


        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        delay(1000);

        for (int y=0; y<8; y++){
            if(test[y + 8] == 1)
                canvas.drawBitmap(ledBitMap, (x - diameterLeds) / 2,diameterLeds * y, paint);

        }
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        //ledThread.delay(1000);


        for (int y=0; y<8; y++){
            if(test[y + 16] == 1)
                canvas.drawBitmap(ledBitMap, (x- diameterLeds) / 2,diameterLeds * y, paint);

        }
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        //ledThread.delay(1000);

        for (int y=0; y<8; y++){
            if(test[y + 24] == 1)
                canvas.drawBitmap(ledBitMap, (x - diameterLeds) / 2,diameterLeds * y, paint);

        }
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        //ledThread.delay(1000);

        for (int y=0; y<8; y++){
            if(test[y + 32] == 1)
                canvas.drawBitmap(ledBitMap, (x - diameterLeds) / 2,diameterLeds * y, paint);

        }

        //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);



        //ledThread.delay(600);

        //delay(1);
    }
}


@Override
public void run() {
    long ticksPS = 1000 / 30;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;

    while(isRunning){

        Canvas canvas = null;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            canvas = ledView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (ledView.getHolder()){
                testTransition(canvas);
            }
        }finally {
           if(canvas != null){
               ledView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `test[]` is a matrix of 40 elements ( 0 or 1)

```
private static int test[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1, 0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0};
```

My goal is to read this arrangement and simulate that 'on or off' of the pattern of the letter B. But when I execute the code, the activity stays a few seconds with the blank screen and after that the circles appear painted on the bitmap but does not alternate the sequence, although the thread seems to be running. Only the last 8 elements of the test array are drawn

Comment: Looks like you're drawing all the bitmaps at the same `x`. And it is not clear why you would expect the "sequence to alternate"; `testTransition()` performs exactly the same function each time it is called: It is not parameterized in any way, and you are not advancing the state of any member variables.

Comment: @greeble31 Yes, the x is the same, when the another 8 elements come I want to redrawn the next 8 elements. The X is the same, because I want to make the POV effect.

Comment: is your while loop running more than once? is the object from test[] being updated? had you debug and seen what is not happening

Comment: The usual is that your while has two steps, 1) process input and change background data ```test[]``` 2) draw the screen; repeat

Comment: Also: your testTransition is blocking the draw, you will see the result only AFTER the method finishes (and delay(1000);) will block its time, and you drawing all the states at the same method, the last one will be shown, both suggestions early can solve the problem

Comment: Thanks @MarcosVasconcelos, I will try your suggestion :)

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Thanks to your help I was able to move towards the answer. THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `SurfaceView` and `lockCanvas()`, the screen is not able to update until *after* you call `unlockCanvasAndPost()`. (I think you were expecting the screen to update midway through `testTransition()`.)

The solution is to implement a state machine, that dirties the SurfaceView based on a timer (for example), and advances the LED display one row on each iteration.